# Why doesn't bs4 find the href attribute?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, href

So I'm learning using atbwp and I'm now doing a program where I open top 5 search results on a website.
It all works up until I have to get the href for each of the top results and open it. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\pyhton\projects\emagSEARCH.py", line 33, in <module>
    webbrowser.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\webbrowser.py", line 86, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\webbrowser.py", line 603, in open
    os.startfile(url)
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType
```

This is how the html looks:

```
<a href="https://comenzi.farmaciatei.ro/ingrijire-personala/ingrijire-corp-si-fata/tratamente-/the-no-brainer-set-the-ordinary-deciem-p344003"> The No-Brainer Set The Ordinary, Deciem</a>
```

And this is the part of my code which won't work for some reason..:

```
Soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
results= Soup.select('.item-title')

numberTabs=min(5,len(results))
print('Opening top '+str(numberTabs)+' top results...')

for i in range(numberTabs):
    url=results[i].get('href')
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

It does what it should until the for loop. It looks pretty much exactly like the example program in the book, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could u provide the full code?

Comment: And what is ur ques? Do u wanna extract the href within the a tag? Is that what u wanna do?

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna extract the `href` under the `a` tag, then use this:

```
html = '<a href="https://comenzi.farmaciatei.ro/ingrijire-personala/ingrijire-corp-si-fata/tratamente-/the-no-brainer-set-the-ordinary-deciem-p344003"> The No-Brainer Set The Ordinary, Deciem</a>'

Soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

url = Soup.find('a')['href']

print(url)

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Output:

```
https://comenzi.farmaciatei.ro/ingrijire-personala/ingrijire-corp-si-fata/tratamente-/the-no-brainer-set-the-ordinary-deciem-p344003
```

U can do the same for all `a` tags in order to get all `hrefs`.